# Compare NumPy arrays with threshold and return the differences

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

In my script, I need to compare pretty big NumPy arrays (2D or 3D), with threshold.
The compare itself can be done easily done with "allclose" function, like that:

```
Threshold = 0.1
if (np.allclose(Arr1, Arr2, Threshold, equal_nan=True)):
    Print('Same')
```

The easiest (yet naive) way to know which cells are not the same is to use a simple for loops code like this one:

```
def CheckWhichCellsAreNotEqualInArrays(Arr1,Arr2,Threshold):
   if not Arr1.shape == Arr2.shape:
       return ['Arrays size not the same']
   Dimensions = Arr1.shape  
   Diff = []
   for i in range(Dimensions [0]):
       for j in range(Dimensions [1]):
           if not np.allclose(Arr1[i][j], Arr2[i][j], Threshold, equal_nan=True):
               Diff.append(',' + str(i) + ',' + str(j) + ',' + str(Arr1[i,j]) + ',' 
               + str(Arr2[i,j]) + ',' + str(Threshold) + ',Fail\n')
       return Diff
```

(and same for 3D arrays - with 1 more for loop)

This way is very slow when the Arrays are big and full of none-equal cells.

Is there a fast straight forward way in case they are not the same - to get a list of the uneven cells? maybe some built-in function in the NumPy itself?

Comment: Produce sample data?

Comment: Yes.
In case the cells are not equal - i would like to get the coordinates of the cell, and the values in both Arrays.

Answer (score 1):

The function `allclose` is equivalent to the combination of [`all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html#numpy.all) and [`isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html#numpy.isclose). So, instead of looping over some dimensions of the arrays, you can apply `isclose` to the entire arrays and then, if needed, apply `all` to some of the axes. (Crucially, `all` takes axis parameter while `allclose` does not). Example with 4D arrays of random data, where some 2D slices are being compared.

```
threshold = 0.1
arr1 = 10 + np.random.normal(size=((40, 30, 20, 10)))
arr2 = arr1 + 0.3 * np.random.normal(size=((40, 30, 20, 10)))
print(np.all(np.isclose(arr1, arr2, threshold), axis=(2, 3)))
```

The prints a 2D array showing which of the slices satisfy `allclose` condition:

```
array([[False,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True, ...,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True, ..., False,  True,  True],
       ..., 
       [False, False,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, ..., False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True, ...,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

That is, `arr1[0, 0]` and `arr2[0, 0]` are not close; but `arr1[0, 1]` and `arr2[0, 1]` are. If necessary, you can then drill down to the element level to find out what exactly fails the `close` condition;  `np.isclose(arr1, arr2, threshold)` has all this information.